# Time difference between unix timestamps

Tags: php

I have to try and work out if a unix timestamp is between 21 days and 49 days from the current date. Can anyone help me to work this out? Thanks!

Comment: Between 21 and 49 days from the current date in which direction? Past or future?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that crucial detail! in the past

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to **SO**!
This should do it:

```
if (($timestamp > time() + 1814400) && ($timestamp < time() + 4233600)) {
 // date is between 21 and 49 days in the FUTURE
}
```

This can be simplified, but I thought you wanted to see a more verbose example :)

I get `1814400` from `21*24*60*60` and `4233600` from `41*24*60*60`.

Edit: I assumed **future** dates. Also note `time()` returns **seconds** (as opposed to milliseconds) since the Epoch in PHP.

This is how you do it in the **past** (since you edited your question):

```
if (($timestamp > time() - 4233600) && ($timestamp < time() - 1814400)) {
 // date is between 21 and 49 days in the PAST
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, perfect! It's between 21 and 49 days in the past, so i'll just modify your snippet

Comment: Be aware that some some days are shorter/longer than 24 hours due to daylight savings etc which makes the calculations shaky. I generally avoid doing calculations on raw timestamps like that and instead use built-in functions for date manipulations.

Answer (score 3):

The PHP5 [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) class is very suited to these sort of tasks.

```
$current = new DateTime();
$comparator = new DateTime($unixTimestamp);
$boundary1 = new DateTime();
$boundary2 = new DateTime();

$boundary1->modify('-49 day'); // 49 days in the past
$boundary2->modify('-21 day'); // 21 days in the past

if ($comparator > $boundary1 && $comparator < $boundary2) {
    // given timestamp is between 49 and 21 days from now
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime` is very useful in these situations, since you can almost speak natural english to it.

```
$ts; // timestamp to check
$d21 = strtotime('-21 days');
$d49 = strtotime('-49 days');

if ($d21 > $ts && $ts > $d49) {
    echo "Your timestamp ", $ts, " is between 21 and 49 days from now.";
}
```

Comment: While in this example it may be trivial, the time() function in PHP 5.2.13 source is one line of C code while the strtotime() function is about 55 lines and calls a LOT of externals. If this was used in a loop especially, time() would be the way to go.

Comment: That's true. But if you only need to set a timestamp once, it's not too expensive when you consider the increased readability.

Comment: +1 For using built-in functions which accounts for locale related date issues.